# Browser replaces '+ ' character with space

Tags: gwt

I am passing an attribute(say, test="ae23+raj") in URL and retrieve it. My URL is 10.203.16.15:8080/page1?test="ae23+raj"

I initially thought this is related to encoding issue and tried out that option too. Later i noticed that after retrieving the attribute value, I printed the value in Window.alert(test). i get "ae23 raj" as value.

I need this value as it's. That is "ae23+raj". I don't know how many such special characters are there which will be replaced by the browser with some other character.  Any help here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look into url encoding

Comment: First of all its not an attribute, its called query parameter.

Comment: Are double quotes also part of query param-value?

Answer (score 0):

Encode/Decode the URL. Here are the JSNI methods that you can use at client side.

```
public static final native String encodeUri(String uri) /*-{
    return encodeURI(uri);
}-*/;

public static final native String decodeUri(String uri) /*-{
    return decodeURI(uri);
}-*/;
```

`%22ae23%2Braj%22` is the encoded value of `"ae23+raj"`. Decode back at client side to get the desired value.

---

There are lots of others ways also in `JavaScript` to encode/decode the URL.

Read about

- [JavaScript decodeURI() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp)
- [JavaScript decodeURIComponent() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp)
- [JavaScript encodeURI() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp)
- [JavaScript encodeURIComponent() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp)

Look at [URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

Read more about [HttpServletResponse#encodeURL()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29) to encode a URL at server side.

---

how to get url query params

```
/** The query params. */
private static Map<String, String> queryParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

static {
    Map<String, List<String>> paramsMap = Window.Location.getParameterMap();
    for (String key : paramsMap.keySet()) {
        List<String> values = paramsMap.get(key);
        if (values.size() > 0) {
            String value = decodeUri(values.get(0));
            queryParams.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
            queryParams.put(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Braj,
Thanks for your reply. This escape method will give me an encode URL. but again I've to parse the url to get the query param value. Instead i can get the param value by parsing the Window.Location.getQueryString() right? Kindly advice which one is preferable. Thanks

Comment: Put this code in your Entry Point class and now use this map anywhere in your application.

Comment: Note: instead of JSNI, just use [`com.google.gwt.http.client.URL`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html)

Comment: Please read  about [encode method](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Please read about [JavaScript encodeURI() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp).

Comment: @Braj, W3Schools? They have far too much Google juice as it is, for being a relatively low-reliability/accuracy source (with a name that misleadingly implies association with the W3C, of which they have none). Mozilla's reference is a better source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Answer (score 0):

In a query-string encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (what most people use: key-value pairs separated by `&` with a `=` as the key-value separator), a `+` is the encoded value of a space: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data.

You have to use `%20` for a space.

…or you could deviate from the de-facto standard, but then you'll have to parse your query-string yourself, as all tools (`HttpServlerRequest#getParameter` and GWT's `Window.Location#getParameter`, to name a few) will decode the `+` into a space.